# Why results of computing eigenvalues in Julia are not integer?

Tags: julia, eigenvalue

I was expecting eigenvalues 0, 1, 3 (that's what I got with WolframAlpha and SageMath). What happened?

```
julia> using LinearAlgebra

julia> eigvals([1 -1 0; -1 2 -1; 0 -1 1])
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
 3.9250536344271737e-17
 0.9999999999999998
 3.0
```

Comment: They basically are. Those are essentially 0, 1 and 3; just with some error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Specifically of note is that eigenvalues of integer matrices aren't always integers.

Comment: This is expected behaviour. Wolfram and Sage probably calculates the eigenvalues symbolically for small matrices. Julia (like Matlab, Numpy, etc.) does it numerically, and there you can expect floating point errors. The errors you see are in line with these other languages.

Comment: @DNF Yes, using Numpy: ```In [5]: print("Eigenvalues : ",np.linalg.eigvals(np.mat("1 -1 0; -1 2 -1;
   ...:  0 -1 1")))
Eigenvalues :  [ 3.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00 -3.36770206e-17]```